# c - Usage of F_GETFL and F_SETFL

Tags: c, file-io, fcntl

While trying to use `fcntl()` with command `F_GETFL` and `F_SETFL`, I got some questions:

1. Why the flag returned by `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` only include a subset of bits of what I set when open file? Does it only show the ones that are modifiable?
2. When use `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flag)`, how should I pass the flag param, do I need to read flag via `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` first, then modify it and pass it? Or internally it just do a bit `&` operation with the new param?
3. Where can I find a full list of the 32 (or less) bits of open file flags?

**Code - [dup_fd_share.c]:**

```
// prove duplicated fd shared file offset and open file status,
// TLPI exercise 5.5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 100

void fd_share() {
    char *fp = "/tmp/fd_share.txt";
    char *buf = "abc\n";
    int write_size = 4;
    int fd, fd2;
    off_t cur, cur2;
    int open_flag, open_flag2;

    // open
    int flag = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND;
    printf("file flag param: %x\n", flag);
    fd = open(fp, flag, 0644);

    // dup
    fd2 = dup(fd);

    // initial offset
    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("fd[%d] offset: %ld\n", fd, cur);
    cur2= lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("fd[%d] offset: %ld\n", fd2, cur2);

    // write, offset change,
    write(fd, buf, 4);
    printf("write %d chars\n", write_size);

    // new offset
    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("fd[%d] offset: %ld\n", fd, cur);
    cur2= lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("fd[%d] offset: %ld\n", fd2, cur2);

    // get original open file flag,
    open_flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    printf("fd[%d] open flag: %x\n", fd, open_flag);
    open_flag2 = fcntl(fd2, F_GETFL);
    printf("fd[%d] open flag: %x\n", fd2, open_flag2);

    // change open file flag,
    open_flag &= ~O_APPEND;
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, open_flag) == -1) {
        printf("failed to set flag\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("change open file flag, remove %s\n", "O_APPEND");

    open_flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    printf("fd[%d] open flag: %x\n", fd, open_flag);
    open_flag2 = fcntl(fd2, F_GETFL);
    printf("fd[%d] open flag: %x\n", fd2, open_flag2);

    close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fd_share();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
file flag param: 642

fd[3] offset: 0
fd[4] offset: 0
write 4 chars
fd[3] offset: 4
fd[4] offset: 4

fd[3] open flag: 402
fd[4] open flag: 402
change open file flag, remove O_APPEND
fd[3] open flag: 2
fd[4] open flag: 2
```

Comment: `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` are modifiers that control the behavior of the `open` call itself; they are not modes that apply to the open file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked:

> Why the flag returned by fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) only include a subset of bits of what I set when open file? Does it only show the ones that are modifiable?

No; it only shows the ones that are "remembered" by the system, such as `O_RDWR`. These can really be called "flags". Some of the other bits ORed into the `oflag` parameter are more like "imperative instructions" to the `open` system call: for example, `O_CREAT` says "please create this file if it doesn't exist" and `O_TRUNC` says "please truncate it", neither of which are "flags". A file that was truncated on creation is indistinguishable from a file that was *not* truncated on creation: they're both just "files". So after `open` is done creating or truncating the file, it doesn't bother to "remember" that history. It only "remembers" important things, like whether the file is open for reading or writing.

**Edited to add:** These different kinds of flags have semi-official names. `O_RDWR` is the "access mode" (remembered, non-modifiable);  `O_APPEND` is an "operating mode" (remembered, usually modifiable); `O_TRUNC` is an "open-time flag" (pertains to the `open` operation itself, not to the file descriptor; therefore not remembered). Notice that the "access mode" is not modifiable — you can't use `fcntl` to turn a read-only fd into a write-only fd.

> When use `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flag)`, how should I pass the flag param, do I need to read flag via `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` first, then modify it and pass it? Or internally it just do a bit `&` operation with the new param?

`F_SETFL` overwrites the flags with *exactly* what you pass in (although it will ignore your puny attempts to set bits-that-aren't-really-flags, such as `O_TRUNC`). IF you want to set a specific flag and leave the other flags as-is, then you must `F_GETFL` the old flags, `|` the new flag in, and then `F_SETFL` the result. This *must* be done as two separate system calls; there is no atomic or thread-safe way to accomplish it as far as I know.

> Where can I find a full list of the 32 (or less) bits of open file flags?

In `fcntl.h` or its documentation (`man fcntl`). For example, on my MacBook the man page says:

```
The flags for the F_GETFL and F_SETFL commands are as follows:

      O_NONBLOCK   Non-blocking I/O; if no data is available to a read call, or if a write operation would block, the read or write
                   call returns -1 with the error EAGAIN.

      O_APPEND     Force each write to append at the end of file; corresponds to the O_APPEND flag of open(2).

      O_ASYNC      Enable the SIGIO signal to be sent to the process group when I/O is possible, e.g., upon availability of data to be
                   read.
```

In other words, there are exactly three bits you can set (or unset) on OS X. Whereas on Linux, the man page says [this](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl):

```
On Linux this command can change only the O_APPEND, O_ASYNC,
O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags.
```

Incidentally, some Linux filesystems have the concept of an "append-only file" at the filesystem level; if you open one of those files and then try to clear the resulting descriptor's `O_APPEND` flag, you'll get an `EPERM` error. The "append-only"-ness of a file can be controlled at the filesystem level using the [`chattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) utility.

---

Here's a more systematic version of your test program. It might not be of interest to you, but I learned something by writing it, so I'm leaving it here. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("/tmp/fd_share.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, 0644);

    // append to empty file
    write(fd, "aaaaaaaaaa", 10);

    off_t cur = lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_SET);
    printf("offset after being set to 1: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    // append
    write(fd, "bbbbbbbb", 8);

    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("offset after appending bbbbbbbb: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    cur = lseek(fd, 2, SEEK_SET);
    printf("offset after being set to 2: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    // now toggle "append mode" to FALSE
    int open_flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, open_flag & ~O_APPEND) == -1) {
        printf("failed to set flag\n");
        return 0;
    }

    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("offset after unsetting O_APPEND: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    cur = lseek(fd, 3, SEEK_SET);
    printf("offset after being set to 3: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    // write without appending
    write(fd, "cccc", 4);

    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("offset after writing cccc: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    // now toggle "append mode" to TRUE
    open_flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, open_flag | O_APPEND) == -1) {
        printf("failed to set flag\n");
        return 0;
    }

    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("offset after unsetting O_APPEND: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    // append
    write(fd, "dd", 2);

    cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("offset after appending dd: %ld\n", (long)cur);

    close(fd);
}
```

The output of this program on my MacBook (as it should be on any POSIX system AFAIK) is:

```
offset after being set to 1: 1
offset after appending bbbbbbbb: 18
offset after being set to 2: 2
offset after unsetting O_APPEND: 2
offset after being set to 3: 3
offset after writing cccc: 7
offset after unsetting O_APPEND: 7
offset after appending dd: 20
```

Answer (score 6):

1) The return of fcnl is a code that described if the function succceded and how:

**RETURN VALUE**

```
   For a successful call, the return value depends on the operation:

   F_DUPFD  The new descriptor.

   F_GETFD  Value of file descriptor flags.

   F_GETFL  Value of file status flags.

   F_GETLEASE
            Type of lease held on file descriptor.

   F_GETOWN Value of descriptor owner.

   F_GETSIG Value of signal sent when read or write becomes possible, or
            zero for traditional SIGIO behavior.

   F_GETPIPE_SZ, F_SETPIPE_SZ
            The pipe capacity.

   F_GET_SEALS
            A bit mask identifying the seals that have been set for the
            inode referred to by fd.

   All other commands
            Zero.

   On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
```

**ERRORS**

```
   EACCES or EAGAIN
          Operation is prohibited by locks held by other processes.

   EAGAIN The operation is prohibited because the file has been memory-
          mapped by another process.

   EBADF  fd is not an open file descriptor

   EBADF  cmd is F_SETLK or F_SETLKW and the file descriptor open mode
          doesn't match with the type of lock requested.

   EBUSY  cmd is F_SETPIPE_SZ and the new pipe capacity specified in arg
          is smaller than the amount of buffer space currently used to
          store data in the pipe.

   EBUSY  cmd is F_ADD_SEALS, arg includes F_SEAL_WRITE, and there
          exists a writable, shared mapping on the file referred to by
          fd.

   EDEADLK
          It was detected that the specified F_SETLKW command would
          cause a deadlock.

   EFAULT lock is outside your accessible address space.

   EINTR  cmd is F_SETLKW or F_OFD_SETLKW and the operation was
          interrupted by a signal; see signal(7).

   EINTR  cmd is F_GETLK, F_SETLK, F_OFD_GETLK, or F_OFD_SETLK, and the
          operation was interrupted by a signal before the lock was
          checked or acquired.  Most likely when locking a remote file
          (e.g., locking over NFS), but can sometimes happen locally.

   EINVAL The value specified in cmd is not recognized by this kernel.

   EINVAL cmd is F_ADD_SEALS and arg includes an unrecognized sealing
          bit.

   EINVAL cmd is F_ADD_SEALS or F_GET_SEALS and the filesystem
          containing the inode referred to by fd does not support
          sealing.

   EINVAL cmd is F_DUPFD and arg is negative or is greater than the
          maximum allowable value (see the discussion of RLIMIT_NOFILE
          in getrlimit(2)).

   EINVAL cmd is F_SETSIG and arg is not an allowable signal number.

   EINVAL cmd is F_OFD_SETLK, F_OFD_SETLKW, or F_OFD_GETLK, and l_pid
          was not specified as zero.

   EMFILE cmd is F_DUPFD and the process already has the maximum number
          of file descriptors open.

   ENOLCK Too many segment locks open, lock table is full, or a remote
          locking protocol failed (e.g., locking over NFS).

   ENOTDIR
          F_NOTIFY was specified in cmd, but fd does not refer to a
          directory.

   EPERM  Attempted to clear the O_APPEND flag on a file that has the
          append-only attribute set.

   EPERM  cmd was F_ADD_SEALS, but fd was not open for writing or the
          current set of seals on the file already includes F_SEAL_SEAL.
```

2) Flags to be set is your choice: :

**F_SETFL (int)**

```
   Set the file status flags to the value specified by arg.  File
   access mode (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR) and file creation
   flags (i.e., O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC) in arg are
   ignored.  On Linux this command can change only the O_APPEND,
   O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags.  It is not
   possible to change the O_DSYNC and O_SYNC flags; see BUGS,
   below.
```

3) [HERE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) you have a complete description.