# How to get flags of opened fd in C?

Tags: c, linux, fcntl

I want to get flags of fd was opened before in C.

But I use `fcntl(fd,F_GETFD,0)` reference by fcntl man page, it always return 1 to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define XSZ(x) (int)(sizeof(x)*2)

int main()
{
    int ret;
    static const char str [] = "hello c program!\n";
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("fd = %d\n", fd);

    ret = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
    printf("flag:%d\n",ret);
    write(fd, str, strlen(str)-1);

    return 0;
}
```

It always print:

```
fd = 3
flag:1
```

What I thought the ret is the sum of `O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT`

Comment: Judging by your history, you don't seem to accept answers that you are given. Are you that unsatisfied by them? Not a great incentive for the SO community.

Comment: @xhienne thanks advice, I accept answer which asked a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use F_GETFL instead of F_GETFD. Also remember to print in octal to compare.

One important thing is not all flags are returned by fcntl. Only the access mode flags are remembered, like O_RDWR. However O_CREATE/O_TRUNC etc. are operating mode or open-time flags which are not remembered by the system and hence not returned.

Here is your modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define XSZ(x) (int)(sizeof(x)*2)

int main()
{
    int ret;
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("fd = %d\n", fd);
    ret = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    perror("fcntl");
    printf("flag:%o\n",ret);
    printf("flag:%o\n",O_RDWR|O_APPEND);
    write(fd, "hello c program\n", strlen("hello c program!\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

here is the output of the above code

```
fd = 3
fcntl: Success
flag:102002
flag:2002
```

Comment: flag:102002, the first 1 mean what?

Comment: that is O_LARGEFILE.  It may be set by default.

Answer (score 1):

`F_GETFD` does not query the open flags, but just `FD_CLOEXEC` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660133/4730685)).

The line

```
write(fd, "hello c program\n", strlen("hello c program!\n"));
```

is wrong, as you query the length of a longer string than what you write, possibly causing a buffer overflow. A safer and more efficient way to do this would be:

```
static const char str [] = "hello c program!\n";
write(fd, str, sizeof(str)-1);
```

The `-1` is needed to avoid writing the terminating 0 byte.

I don't know the purpose of

```
#define XSZ(x) (int)(sizeof(x)*2)
```

but casting `size_t` (the result type of `sizeof()`) to `int` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Is there anyway to get flags of opened fd? Sorry for some dummy code.

Comment: There is [`F_GETFL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574626/4730685).